# jQuery UI: Datepicker keep showing the default date format after changing

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

My datepicker is showing the default format `mm/dd/yy` even after changing the format to `yy-mm-dd`

This is my `script.js`

```
$(function(){
 $( "#date" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
 $( "#date" ).datepicker();
})
```

Please help.

Comment: Why are you calling datepicker twice? That's most certainly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

You are calling the datepicker twice. The second time without any options, so it is called with its default options and seems to override the first one

Here's a fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/qG4PC/